# Android: How to get meta data of a particular mp3 song

Tags: android, mp3

I know that the songs artist,album etc can be displayed by using MediaStore.Audio class. But it displays the list of artists,albums etc. The problem is when I click an artist name(displayed as list in my activity), all the songs with that particular artist should be displayed.

How can I filter the songs based on meta data (album/artist etc). How to get metadata of that particular song ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter based on the artist that the user clicked, you need to requery the database.

Below is an example of such a query.

```
String query = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND _display_name LIKE '%.mp3' AND artist LIKE " + artistStringHere;
```

Comment: So, I think we have to separate the artistnames in the string 'query'.Can we store each string in a String array ?

Answer (score 0):

Read through the mp3 and find the id3 and id3+. However, dealing with mp3 music usually indicates piracy.

Comment: How can we access the id3 of the mp3?

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever works perfectly but it runs in api level 10 and above, is there any similar one for api level 8 ?

Comment: Learn about the mp3 format on how to access mp3 blocks